# reading public var valid of subclass of NSTimer fails with 'isValid only defined for abstract class'

Tags: ios, swift, abstract-class, nstimer, subclassing

I have created a subclass of NSTimer which adds (i hope) the pause and resume function to scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval function.

```
class HCTimer: NSTimer {

    var hcTimerInterval :NSTimeInterval!
    var hcTarget :AnyObject!
    var hcSelector :Selector!
    var hcUserInfo :AnyObject!
    var hcRepeats :Bool!
    var hcTimer :HCTimer!

    class func pausableScheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target aTarget: AnyObject, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> HCTimer {

        let hcInstanceTimer = super.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti,target: aTarget, selector: aSelector, userInfo: userInfo, repeats: yesOrNo) as! HCTimer

        hcInstanceTimer.hcTimerInterval = ti
        hcInstanceTimer.hcTarget = aTarget
        hcInstanceTimer.hcSelector = aSelector
        hcInstanceTimer.hcUserInfo = userInfo!
        hcInstanceTimer.hcRepeats = yesOrNo
        hcInstanceTimer.hcTimer = hcInstanceTimer

        return hcInstanceTimer
    }

    func pause() {
        self.invalidate()
    }

    func resume() {
        self.hcTimer = HCTimer.pausableScheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(hcTimerInterval, target: hcTarget, selector: hcSelector, userInfo: hcUserInfo, repeats: hcRepeats)
    }
}
```

To use the new class in the existing viewController, i replaced the existing properties of type NSTimer with HCTimer. The timer is started when a button is pressed and the timer is not valid.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var severityButtonTimer = HCTimer()

    @IBAction func sortOnSeverityButtonTouchInside(sender: UIButton) {

        // Start animation if none running
        if (!severityButtonTimer.valid) {
            // Change sort order
```

The code compiles successfully, but when the function the value 'valid' of the HCTimer instance is read it fails with the following exception.

```
2016-04-08 12:03:25.234 homecaremonitor[45750:17518480] *** Terminating app     due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -isValid only defined for abstract class.  Define -[homecaremonitor.HCTimer isValid]!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4c5d85     __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111269deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4c5cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f9477b9 NSRequestConcreteImplementation + 229
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010f95aa19 -[NSTimer(NSTimer) isValid] + 39
    5   homecaremonitor                     0x000000010ef43f78
```

Still trying to fix this, any help is appreciated !
Cheers,
Peter

Replaced the subclass `HCTimer` with `HCTimerWrapper` as adviced by Wain

```
class HCTimerWrapper {

    var hcTimerInterval :NSTimeInterval!
    var hcTarget :AnyObject!
    var hcSelector :Selector!
    var hcUserInfo :AnyObject!
    var hcRepeats :Bool!
    var hcTimer :NSTimer!
    var valid : Bool {
        get {
            if hcTimer != nil  {
                return hcTimer.valid
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    func pausableScheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target aTarget: AnyObject, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) {

        let hcInstanceTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti,target: aTarget, selector: aSelector, userInfo: userInfo, repeats: yesOrNo)

        self.hcTimerInterval = ti
        self.hcTarget = aTarget
        self.hcSelector = aSelector
        self.hcUserInfo = userInfo!
        self.hcRepeats = yesOrNo
        self.hcTimer = hcInstanceTimer  
    }

    func pause() {
        self.hcTimer.invalidate()
    }

    func resume() {
        self.hcTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.hcTimerInterval, target: self.hcTarget, selector: self.hcSelector, userInfo: self.hcUserInfo, repeats: self.hcRepeats)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a subclass of `NSTimer`, create a wrapper which exposes the functionality you need. You already have some confusion in your code about the `hcTimer` and what it is and is used for (I expect this hasn't become evident yet), your wrapper can also avoid that.

So, your wrapper will optionally contain an `NSTimer` instance. Never call `NSTimer()` - this is effectively what your code is currently doing. You should either have no timer or you should have a fully created and scheduled timer instance.

Comment: This supports your statement: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Nov/msg00389.html. Apparently, NSTimer is (part of) a class cluster.

Comment: Also see the subclassing notes from the NSTimer docs, presented here in their entirety: "You should not attempt to subclass NSTimer." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html